# Use polymer expression on main html site

Tags: polymer

short question: Is it possible to use polymer expressions on a normal html site? So that I could write `{{ 1+ 1 }}` somewhere and it would be evaluated to 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean "without including anything of polymer", than the short answer would be "no". Otherwise here is an example for [using a polymer expression outside of a polymer element](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#autobinding):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="/components/platform/platform.js"></script>
  <link href="/components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">    
</head>

<body unresolved>

  <template is="auto-binding">
    1 + 1 is {{1+1}}
  </template>

</body>

</html>
```