# Polymer core-scaffold change tool using data binding

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer

I'm using [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/) on my website, more specifically the [Core-Scaffold](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-scaffold).

Here's some sample code I made:

```
<core-scaffold>
  <core-header-panel navigation flex mode="seamed">
    <core-toolbar>Application</core-toolbar>
    <core-menu theme="core-light-theme">
      <core-item icon="settings" label="item1"></core-item>
      <core-item icon="settings" label="item2"></core-item>
    </core-menu>
  </core-header-panel>
  <div tool>Title</div>
  <div>Content goes here...</div>
</core-scaffold>
<script>
  var menuItems = document.querySelector("core-menu");

  menuItems.addEventListener("core-select", function(){
    console.log(menuItems.selected);
  });
</script>
```

What I want is that on clicking one of the `core-item`'s from the `core-menu`, that the `<div tool>Title</div>` content changes correspondingly. I've already been able to attach an event listener to the selection of the buttons, but I dont quite know how to keep the tool up to date. Polymer has a two-way [data binding](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding.html) that I don't fully master yet.

So, what would be the most advised way of updating the `tool`-div with the pressed menu-item-label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this easily with two way data binding. [`<core-menu>` exposes a `selectedItem` attribute](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-menu) which you can bind on. To get data binding you can set up a bound template manually, but you probably just want to make your app itself a component. Like so:

```
<my-app></my-app>

<polymer-element name='my-app'>
  <template>
    <core-scaffold>
      <core-header-panel navigation flex mode="seamed">
        <core-toolbar>Application</core-toolbar>
        <core-menu theme="core-light-theme" selectedItem='{{item}}'>
          <core-item icon="settings" label="item1"></core-item>
          <core-item icon="settings" label="item2"></core-item>
        </core-menu>
      </core-header-panel>
      <div tool>{{item.label}}</div>
      <div>Content goes here...</div>
    </core-scaffold>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-app', {
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this without needing to create a separate `'my-app'`-element?

Comment: Yeah there are a couple ways, the easiest is to use auto binding templates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824576/use-polymer-expression-on-main-html-site . That said I'd encourage you to write your own elements, as it gives you a convenient place to declare functions filters and computed properties, hold encapsulated state, and enables you to use components of your site in new reusable ways!

Comment: The problem is that it's my main page, the `core-scaffold` is the main element containing all my data, so doing this would require me to write the majority (if not all) of my code inside a template of a `core-scaffold`... I tried your example and it works, but then I can't find a way to bind the eventListeners on the `core-menu`.

Comment: Polymer can (handle binding events for you)[http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding.html#event-handling-and-data-binding], or you can put code inside of (`domReady`)[http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods] and using ($.id)[http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding]. If you've got a more specific question, just ask, I look at just about every question tagged Polymer on the site :)

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't quit understand how to get it working without making into a polymer-element. I tried using the auto-binding, but I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I have just created a separate polymer-element as you suggested the first time, wasn't that difficult to implement and now the rest of my code has a better structure as well. So there's no need for a new jsbin, thanks!